# AES encryption in PHP - AES decryption in GO

Tags: php, go, encryption, openssl, aes

I am working on a legacy code written in PHP that I have to migrate to GO. We are required to store encrypted data, and decrypt on demand.

Because the legacy code will still have to run until everything is migrated to GO, I need to use the same encrypt / decrypt methods in GO too.

I have been strugling with this issue for the last 10 hours. I have tried (I think) all the Stackoverflow suggestions + many others.

The servers are running OpenSSL 1.1.1a. I have found and tested something helpful, but without success:

https://dequeue.blogspot.com/2014/11/decrypting-something-encrypted-with.html

I do not have to much knowledge about encryption in general, but I can understand it's basics.

So, if there is anyone kind enough to give me some suggestions ... please.

**PHP legacy code**

```php
    var $encryption_key = 'XXX';
    var $cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';

    function encrypt($text) {
        global $encryption_key, $cipher;

        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher));
        $data = openssl_encrypt($text, $cipher, $encryption_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

        return base64_encode($iv . $data);
    }

    function decrypt($text) {
        global $encryption_key, $cipher;

        $data = base64_decode($text);
        $iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_len);
        $data = substr($data, $iv_len);

        return openssl_decrypt($data, $cipher, $encryption_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    }
```

**Last code tested in GO for decrypting data (ignore the block below and scroll for updated code)**

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "crypto/aes"
        "crypto/cipher"
        "crypto/md5"
        "encoding/base64"
        "fmt"
    )

    func main(){
        result, _ := DecryptString(`password`, `U2FsdGVkX1+ywYxveBnekSnx6ZP25nyPsWHS3oqcuTo=`)
        fmt.Printf("Decrypted string is: %s", result)
    }

    var openSSLSaltHeader string = "Salted_" // OpenSSL salt is always this string + 8 bytes of actual salt

    type OpenSSLCreds struct {
        key []byte
        iv  []byte
    }

    // Decrypt string that was encrypted using OpenSSL and AES-256-CBC
    func DecryptString(passphrase, encryptedBase64String string) ([]byte, error) {
        data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encryptedBase64String)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        saltHeader := data[:aes.BlockSize]
        if string(saltHeader[:7]) != openSSLSaltHeader {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Does not appear to have been encrypted with OpenSSL, salt header missing.")
        }
        salt := saltHeader[8:]
        creds, err := extractOpenSSLCreds([]byte(passphrase), salt)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return decrypt(creds.key, creds.iv, data)
    }

    func decrypt(key, iv, data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
        if len(data) == 0 || len(data)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("bad blocksize(%v), aes.BlockSize = %v\n", len(data), aes.BlockSize)
        }
        c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        cbc := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(c, iv)
        cbc.CryptBlocks(data[aes.BlockSize:], data[aes.BlockSize:])
        out, err := pkcs7Unpad(data[aes.BlockSize:], aes.BlockSize)
        if out == nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return out, nil
    }

    // openSSLEvpBytesToKey follows the OpenSSL (undocumented?) convention for extracting the key and IV from passphrase.
    // It uses the EVP_BytesToKey() method which is basically:
    // D_i = HASH^count(D_(i-1) || password || salt) where || denotes concatentaion, until there are sufficient bytes available
    // 48 bytes since we're expecting to handle AES-256, 32bytes for a key and 16bytes for the IV
    func extractOpenSSLCreds(password, salt []byte) (OpenSSLCreds, error) {
        m := make([]byte, 48)
        prev := []byte{}
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            prev = hash(prev, password, salt)
            copy(m[i*16:], prev)
        }
        return OpenSSLCreds{key: m[:32], iv: m[32:]}, nil
    }

    func hash(prev, password, salt []byte) []byte {
        a := make([]byte, len(prev)+len(password)+len(salt))
        copy(a, prev)
        copy(a[len(prev):], password)
        copy(a[len(prev)+len(password):], salt)
        return md5sum(a)
    }

    func md5sum(data []byte) []byte {
        h := md5.New()
        h.Write(data)
        return h.Sum(nil)
    }

    // pkcs7Unpad returns slice of the original data without padding.
    func pkcs7Unpad(data []byte, blocklen int) ([]byte, error) {
        if blocklen <= 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid blocklen %d", blocklen)
        }
        if len(data)%blocklen != 0 || len(data) == 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid data len %d", len(data))
        }
        padlen := int(data[len(data)-1])
        if padlen > blocklen || padlen == 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid padding")
        }
        pad := data[len(data)-padlen:]
        for i := 0; i < padlen; i++ {
            if pad[i] != byte(padlen) {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid padding")
            }
        }
        return data[:len(data)-padlen], nil
    }
```

The code written in GO should be able to decrypt data encrypted in PHP. The only result that I get is an error: **Error: Does not appear to have been encrypted with OpenSSL, salt header missing.**

**UPDATE: Go code updated**

The code below *almost* works. IV, key, cipher binary text are all the same as in PHP, but the final result is still encrypted (or wrongly decrypted)

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "crypto/aes"
        "crypto/cipher"
        "encoding/base64"
        "fmt"
    )

    func main() {

        var stringToDecode string = "base64_encode(SOME_PHP_ENCRYPTED_USING_THE_PHP_CODE_ABOVE)"
        var cipherKey = []byte("myprivatekey")

        content, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(stringToDecode)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Cipher key: ", string(cipherKey))
        fmt.Println("Cipher key length: ", len(cipherKey))

        cipherText := content

        cipherBlock, err := aes.NewCipher(cipherKey)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        iv := cipherText[:aes.BlockSize]
        fmt.Println("iv:", base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(iv))
        fmt.Println("Cipher text:", string(cipherText[aes.BlockSize:]))

        cipherText = cipherText[aes.BlockSize:]

        fmt.Println("Cipher text binary: ", string(cipherText))

        if len(cipherText)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("Cipher text (len=%d) is not a multiple of the block size (%d)", len(cipherText), aes.BlockSize))
        }

        mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(cipherBlock, iv)
        mode.CryptBlocks(cipherText, cipherText)

        // The output is not decrypted as expected
        fmt.Printf("The result: %s\n", string(cipherText))
    }
```

Comment: You say `OpenSSL salt is always this string + 8 bytes of actual salt`, however, PHP using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` this means that it is random for each encryption.

Comment: Your Go lib seems to implement a bunch of extra fluff that your PHP does not. Notice that the Go code is a _lot_ longer? You'll either need to implement the fluff in PHP, or trim the fluff out of the Go code.

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch i have reduced GO code to basics.

Comment: I have experienced a LSB MSB difference with C and C# packages before when I was writing a Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm. Maybe it's something like that?

Comment: @Adryan this is resolved . I  am facing same problem.. but not able to find out solution